# JS: The Good Parts: The `superior` function

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am trying to understand an example from Douglas Crockford’s “Javascript: The Good Parts”, Chapter 1 “Good Parts”, regarding inheritance. Specifically the `superior` function. In the book it is as follows:

```
Object.method('superior', function(name) {

  var that = this, method = that[name];
  return function() {
    // Why can’t this just be `return method`?
    return method.apply(that, arguments);
  };
});
```

As mentioned in the code comment above I don’t understand why we need to use `apply` when simply returning the function itself seems to work find in my experimentation.

#### Supplementary Info

The above uses a `method` function defined as

```
Function.prototype.method = function(name, func) {
  this.prototype[name] = func;
  return this;
};
```

Comment: That's some pretty convoluted code. Also note that mutating built-in objects is *very* bad practice...

Comment: I realise the book is old but I feel there is still value to be had some the stuff described therein. Anyway, just trying to understand the example in its context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a convoluted way of doing things indeed. One possible advantage is that the resulting function will automatically bind to the initial `this` context (i.e you will subsequently be able to call it without having to reference the instance).

I guess the following implementation would reveal the intention more clearly:

```js
Object.method("superior", function(name) {
    var that = this, method = that[name];
    return method.bind(that);
});
```

(This possible advantages is not directly apparent from the `coolcat` example on the next page as the `get_name` method does not make use of a `this` context.)